# Make Files Accessible by Perl Script but Blocked from Web Access - IIS6

Tags: windows, perl, iis-6

I am using perl on a windows 2003 server with IIS6.  I have written a script that needs to access confidential files uploaded by the user.  The files are stored in a folder in the cgi-bin.  However, I do not want the files to be accessible via weblink.  So, I have 'read access' for this particular folder disabled in IIS.

The files are not accessible via weblink, but I need for the user to be able to open the documents that he/she uploaded.

The users logins (usernames and passwords) are stored in the cgi-bin in a csv file.

I've searched the database but couldn't find anything exactly matching this situation.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Encrypt them and put the key in the Perl script?

Comment: Thank you, Triplee.  I will try that option and report back.

Comment: Is there a good example somewhere on how to do this?  I'm now trying PHP.  This is the code that I have (works without encryption), but it will not upload the encrypted file.  Sorry...new to this.

'if (isset ($_POST['submit'])) { // Handle form.
  $document = fread(fopen($_FILES['thefile']['tmp_name'], "r"), filesize($_FILES['thefile']['tmp_name']));
$encoded_document =  base64_encode($document);
@mkdir ("files/$username/$newdir"); 
if (move_uploaded_file ($encoded_document,"files/$username/$newdir/$encoded_document"))'

Answer (score 0):

Unless I've misunderstood your question, you're trying to limit user access at the application level, not the service level.

If you want users of your web app to be able to access files that they uploaded then your authorization check needs to be done in the application, as opposed to at the edge (by web server).

So every uploaded file is tagged with it's owner (a database record, or a per-owner directory) and access to files is restricted by a small bit of code that checks the authenticated user against the file owner.

The directory in which the files live is readable and writable by the web server user, as that's the user the perl will run as, but it is not configured into IIS as availble for regular HTTP GET access.
It is neither under the HTML document root, nor under the CGI-BIN directory. It is a completely separate directory.

Comment: Thank you, Len.  That is a helpful idea.  However, I would still like to have the files encrypted until they are actually accessed by the script.

Comment: keys and password do not belong in programs. Put them in config files and have the program read them as needed. Then you make the web server user the only user that has read access to the config file, and you remove write permission if you can, so that nobody can accidentally save over the top of the config.